# SQL Shift column down 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to subtract a value from a past time period with the value in the present time period.

*This is what I have:

```
Date,  present, past (identical to present)
 Jan,   100,        100
 Feb,   200,        200
March,  300,        300
April,  400,        400
```

*This is what I want;

```
Date,  present, past (past column shifted down 1 row)

     Jan,    100,       0
     Feb,   200,        100
    March,  300,        200
    April,  400,        300
```

Sample of code:

```
SELECT
      [month],
      sum([money]) as present,
      sum([money]) as past
FROM database
group by [month]
```

Comment: We love that you're here and we need to see your code.

Comment: ^I have updated some sample code. I am trying to do this without joins

Comment: this is exactly how your data looks you don't have a date field of type date in your data?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without joins?

Comment: ^I am making CTEs that are doing different calculations off of a temp table. I suspect the self joins I used within the CTEs to accomplish this task before is having a large impact on performance

Comment: Then that should be part of the question and you should include the CTE code.  We can't answer the question if you don't tell us what it is... Joins should be the fastest way to anything in SQL.   You may need to make an index or two.  Show us the original code you are trying to speed up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `LAG()` function, as in:

```
select
  d,
  present,
  lag(past, 1, 0) over (order by d) as past  
from t
order by d
```

Result:

```
d          present past
---------- ------- ----
2019-01-01 100        0
2019-02-01 200      100
2019-03-01 300      200
2019-04-01 400      300
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1112/2).

For the record, here's the data script:

```
create table t (
  d date,
  present int,
  past int
);

insert into t (d, present, past) values ('2019-01-01', 100, 100);
insert into t (d, present, past) values ('2019-02-01', 200, 200);
insert into t (d, present, past) values ('2019-03-01', 300, 300);
insert into t (d, present, past) values ('2019-04-01', 400, 400);
```

Comment: You are assuming the date field is a date -- isn't it just a character string with some random abbreviation of the month?

Comment: @Hogan Yes, that's the assumption. Otherwise, it doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Or we need to make a lookup table to join to to get the order

Answer (score 0):

`LAG()` with an ORDER BY (a constant 1 for natural order)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(date NVARCHAR(20), present int, past int)
INSERT @T values('Jan',100,100),('Feb',200,200),('March',300,300),('April',400,400)

SELECT 
    date,
    present,
    LAG(present) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM 
    @T
```

Comment: I think this would put 'Feb' before 'Jan'

Comment: No, it would not :)

Comment: That is not an ordinal order indicator, it is a sub query.

Comment: I see... so natural order => random

Comment: Yes, random, however, there was no row indicator in the original question...so I assumed it would be in proper order. The order in which the results are evaluated. If not affected by other clauses then it would be the "natural" order of the data.

Comment: In SQL there is no such thing as proper order

Comment: I meant, the order in which the results are evaluated, If not affected by other clauses. I call that the "natural" order of the data.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean and yes it will work for some of the time -- maybe even a long time.  When it stops working is when I have to come into work on a weekend and fix the bug.  That is annoying.  SQL does not have a natural order or a constant order if you don't put in an order by clause.

Comment: I agree it is dangerous to assume there is a natural order, however, given a table with no order, grouping, or joining then I would think the order of the data would be preserved as it lays in the physical file, such as a heap. A heap has an internal row indicator but it would be dangerous to assume, in a query, that the heap will always adhere to its internal ordering mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your table has duplicate values, and all can be simplified by starting with the simple table of 2 columns `(date, value)`

`[present]` is the value, and past is limply the lag of `[value]`

Then `sum()` and subtract as required

In other words, try starting with

```
d          present
---------- -------
2019-01-01 100
2019-02-01 200
2019-03-01 300
2019-04-01 400
```